# ngRoute: cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-material, angular-routing

I have been trying to implement routing in my project but find it difficult to do so. Here is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 0.11.2 used here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>-->
```

```
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>

<section ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-view></div>
</section>


<!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.11.2 used here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

and here is my app.js file:

```
 (function(){
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module('math_teacher', ['ngMaterial']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/welcome',{
      templateUrl: 'welcome.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/welcome'});
  }]);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function(){

  }]);
  app.controller('TutorialsController', ['$scope', function(){
  }]);
})();
```

and here is my welcome.html to test whether my route was working

```
<h1>Welcome to this page</h1>
<p>This really shows that the route is at work</p>
```

on running this on my server here is what am seeing in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:24(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:6
>
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=math_teacher&p1=Er…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4138r @ angular.js:323g @ angular.js:4099ab @ angular.js:4025d @ angular.js:1452uc @ angular.js:1473Jd @ angular.js:1367(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26304a @ angular.js:2762c @ angular.js:3032

Pls help

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution!
after adding 
    'ngRoute'
to the dependencies it still doesn't work

All I did was to add my script after angularjs script and not before it

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `'ngRoute'` module in your app.

```
 var app = angular.module('math_teacher', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
```